# Over filled oil 2014 Mercedes Sprinter diesel with the high oil light on for say 20 miles?

Tags: mercedes-benz

What is the danger of driving a 2014 Mercedes Sprinter diesel with the HI oil light on for say 20 miles after an oil change added approximately 1quart too much?

Comment: Danger may be the oil may foam due to cavitation from the crankshaft and cause engine bearing failure. Drain out a quart. Most engines will tolerate 1qt overfill, some may not.

Answer (score 1):

Yep and the seals for the crank shaft may start to leak causing a oil leak out of the engine and a potential MOT failure next time if it gets too messy. I would not worry too much about driving it 20 miles though, would keep the revs on the low side to not increase the pressure in the sump too much. But that´s me...